# Import currency type with Feeds import

Tags: entities, feeds

Is there a way to import a currency type when doing a Feeds import?  I have tried using the Feeds Tamper add on and am currently looking at [this solution](http://drupal.org/node/1274518#comment-6188606).  It seems that I am trying to reinvent the wheel :)  I have created a cck field that was called "price" as a text field and it worked beautifully.  I created this as a currency field and the new "price" currency field doesn't show up as an option to map to on the mapper UI.  I exported the Feed Import and added the field manually and then [imported it back in](http://drupal.org/node/1006292#comment-5824308).  When I run the import it doesn't bring over the value that is mapped.

Comment: It's not clear what your trouble is. I recommend you spell it out rather than asking others to replicate/research it. Not sure if this will help, but are you aware of the Feeds Tamper module? It solves a lot of issues.

Comment: I apologize for the slacker question.  I hate it when people do that on SO.  I will try to modify it to show more info.

Comment: I modified the question.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Line 18 of feeds/mappers/content.inc  

`if (in_array($field['type'], array('text', 'number_integer', 'number_decimal', 'number_float')))`  I think this is where the issue lies.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a fairly hacky answer for now. In feeds/mappers/content.inc I modified the function **content_feeds_set_target** after I added the *money* type to the array of included field types in line 18

```
function content_feeds_set_target($node, $target, $value) {

  $field = isset($node->$target) ? $node->$target : array();

  // Handle multiple value fields.
  if (is_array($value)) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($value as $v) {
      if (!is_array($v) && !is_object($v)) {
        $field[$i]['value'] = $v;
      }
      $i++;
    }
  }
  else {
    $field[0]['value'] = $value;
    //added these two lines to take care of the Money field    
    $field[0]['amount'] = $value;
    $field[0]['currency'] = 'USD';
  }

  $node->$target = $field;
}
```

*I know that this isn't the way to develop in Drupal and most likely I need to set up another content type or something along that line but this helped me (who am a complete noob to Drupal) to get started importing the price field.*